# Print a number to variable number of decimal places

Tags: c

I wanted to print a number to variable number of decimal places in C. 
I have written the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
    {   int a;
        printf("Upto which number of decimal places you want to print value of '2.554648' ?");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("Value of '2.554648 upto %d number of decimal places = %.af", a, 2.554648);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There's something missing from your question. That would be an actual question.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: to make it a real SO ques, what's the result you got from your code? and what's the result you was expecting?

Comment: BTW, use `int main()` or `int main(void)` instead of `main`

Comment: where is the value 2.554648 defined in a variable, so it can be printed?

Comment: this portion of the printf  '%.af", a' should be: '%.*f", a,variable to print' (note: I might have the syntax a bit off, as I rarely use such a format converter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `*` in [`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) to mark how many decimal places you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;

    printf("Upto which number of decimal places you want to print value of '2.554648' ?");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Value of '2.554648 upto %d number of decimal places = %.*f", a, a, 2.554648);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need the `*` format specifier. Here is a short example(see in [ideone](http://ideone.com/kbgODB)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 5;
    double temp = 5.0 / 7;
    printf("%.*f",a, temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski okay, removing the `l`, though C89 is quite old already

Comment: True, though you might still find it common in embedded solutions like C compilers for microcontrollers.