# Adjust the decimal places in a format string programatically and safely

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, floating-point-precision, format-string

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle changing a format string on the fly in C without opening an uncontrolled format string vulnerability.

I have data in a struct which contains the floating point number and an unsigned integer number which corresponds to the number of significant figures for printing.

I would like to use the integer to generate the precision for format strings on the fly so that:

`3` generates `"%.3g"`

`21` generates `"%.21g"`

Is there a safe way to do this without opening my code up to exploits?

Comment: Another dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26844907/694576

Comment: Apparently my search-fu failed.

Comment: C is no secret science, so it's in `printf()`'s documentation. I know the man-page is "huge" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're in luck. You need to make use of the precision field in the format string. In that, you can provide a `.*` notation and supply the corresponding integer argument holding the  value of the precision.

You can use the following pattern to make this happen, example with `printf()`.

```
 printf("%.*g", int_precision, decimal_to_print)
```